# Read and write files in android

Tags: java, android, file

I have an ordinary java class `SvmPredict` within my android project that contains a method that takes two files as parameters - reading from the first and writing to the second.

```
public class SvmPredict {
    public void run (File input, File output);
}
```

`SvmPredict.run()` uses the java ordinary method to read & write files into the local project.

On the other hand, my activity `PredectionActivity` will instantiate this class `SvmPredict` and use it.

Is this a correct method because it doesn't work? But I don't know the reason why.

Should I transfome `SvmPredict` to an android activity? And how in this case could I read and write into files?

Comment: can you be a bit more precise what exactly " it doesn't work" mean? have you set the filepermission in the android manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>`

Comment: I mean by "doesn't work" that when I instantiate `SvmPredict` class from my `PredectionActivity` it cannot read and write Files 

I placed the file to read in the android project which is also the path of file to write

Comment: If the files are inside android project then you need to create file instances using android_resource URI schema.

Comment: And you can't write to anything within the project, only in the internal (private) or external (originally sdcard) storage.  It's only the later which requires Manifest permission(s).